# Positioning Across Different Browsers

Tags: position, absolute

I've run into an issue where an element that is on its own level on a page is positioned differently in different browsers. It is the slideshow at; 
http://nevillebeandesign.com/Tattoo/bobShaw.html
In Safari, it is several pixels higher up than in Firefox and Chrome, and significantly lower in Opera.  I've had to reduce its size so it wouldn't overlap the red lines in the background image (originally in Safari it fit tightly between the 2 red lines). Is there some kind of fix I can put in the document head that would adjust positioning for different browsers? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is somewhat related to the <object> element you're using, which is inserted inside a cell. Also, many old quirks come into play since you're relying on an outdated markup structure (tabular). Basically, your element is called inline-block in CSS. This implies that it can accept the vertical-align property. In your case, however, you force browsers to use their internal algorithms because you've used the align attribute (deprecated). That's why you see a different vertical alignment in various browsers. To fix this, provide the object's element with a stated height and try to apply the 'vertical-align: middle' CSS declaration to the object itself. You can also try to set an appropriate 'line-height' on the object's container.